# Energy-momentum tensor property in free theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism

We consider a free lagrangian $$ 
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2
$$
The energy-momentum tensor is defined as 
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = (\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial_\nu\phi)-g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}
$$

I am trying to show that$$
\partial_\mu(x^\rho T^{\mu\sigma}-x^\sigma T^{\mu\rho})=0
$$
I know that from the lagrangian we can use the fact that the KG equation satisfies it so $(\partial^2+m^2)\phi=0$ but when I substitute in, my terms do not cancel out. Is there any property that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you check that energy momentum tensor is conserve?

Comment: Please add your derivation into the answer.

Comment: Use the product rule and that $\partial_\mu T^{\mu \sigma} = 0$ and notice that $\partial_\mu x^\rho = \delta^\rho_\mu$, $\partial_\mu x^\sigma = \delta^\sigma_\mu$, then use that $T^{\sigma \rho} = T^{\rho \sigma}$ as you can see from the EM-tensor you derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just “brute force” the derivative using product rule. No plugging in Klein-Gordon equation.

What you really need is $\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu \nu}=0$ and symmetry of your stress energy tensor (trivial to check).

Comment: Yeah, once I use the facts you mentioned this was trivial. Thank you very much!(and sorry for the "trivial" question)

Comment: No problem, and don’t be ashamed of trivialities; 9 months ago I would have had great difficulty with this problem.